# .readkey(true) and converting to string

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding in c# and I was wondering if you could help with my issue.
I have the following c#:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo Input;
string getHidden = "";

Console.Write("Input Your Hidden String: ");
do
{
  Input = Console.ReadKey(true);
  getHidden =                                 //<--- here
} while (Input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
Console.ReadLine();
```

What I am looking to do with this code, is to get what keys were pressed from `input` and convert them into a string and set them as `getHidden`.

What would be the most effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StringBuilder to do it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ConsoleKeyInfo Input;
Console.Write("Input Your Hidden String: ");
do
{
     Input = Console.ReadKey(true);
     sb.Append(Input.KeyChar);                            //<--- here
} while (Input.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
Console.ReadLine();
```

After that, sb.ToString() will give you the whole string.

Comment: hey there, thanks - this works! But how would I go about comparing `sb.ToString()` to a predefined string such as `const string = "preset"`. As it doesnt seem that the `if( == ) {}` works?

Comment: If we assume your const string is : `const string myConstString = "preset";`, You can use like `if(sb.ToString() == myConstString) { }`

Comment: Do keep in mind what happens when you press, say, F1.

Comment: @zxc you have to accept that answer if it is working.